# How to set a variable using a scalar-valued tSQL function in SSIS SQL Task

Tags: ssis

I have a tSQL scalar-valued function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[MyDB_GetJobId]
(
)
RETURNS [uniqueidentifier]
```

Its results need to go into a SSIS user variable `vJobId`, declared as `String`.
SqlStatementSource is `EXEC ? = dbo.MyDB_GetJobId()`; result set is as follows: `Result Name`: 0; `Variable Name`: `User::vJobId`.

It does not work, the error message is as follows

`"EXEC ? = dbo.MyDB_GetJobId()" failed with the following error: "No value given for one or more required parameters.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.`

Connection is fine (a plain SQL request runs ok), no input parameters, ... Could you help? Thanks.

Comment: ResultSet is Single row

Comment: http://www.sqlis.com/post/The-Execute-SQL-Task.aspx describes how to use stored procedures, but not the functions. Also, I am not sure I understand 0s and ?s, maybe this is where the problem is.

Comment: It runs now, but the user variable value is not set. I have tried `SELECT dbo.MyDB_GetJobId() AS vJobId` and set `Result Name` to vJobId, but the user variable is still empty.

Comment: And that's to be expected. EXEC goes with stored procedures, SELECT is for table and scalar objects. This function is a scalar valued one.

Comment: @Siva: In Locals, when the brekapoint set at the next task is hit. Using convert as `SELECT convert(nvarchar(50), dbo.MyDB_GetJobId()) AS vJobId` did not help.

Comment: @billinkc: sorry never come across SELECT and user functions in combination, I have literally 3-4 days of SSIS exprrience, so I guess some silly errors are expected.

Comment: @Siva: works fine now, null result was actually correct; updated my table and got a non-trivial output. Many thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I initially went down the path of trying to use a Parameter Mapping with a direction of Return but that was incorrect.

Instead, I have my Execute SQL Task configured as shown. My `ResultSet` is a "Single Row". My `SQLStatement` is simply "SELECT dbo.MyDB_GetJobID()"

[image: Execute SQL General tab]

In the result set tab, since this is a ResultSet type of Single Row, then we provide a mapping per column with a zero based ordinal system.

[image: Execute SQL Result Set tab]

This is an example demonstrating the result being assigned to the variable `User::SingleRow`. You can ignore `Other` as I was trying to make it work with via the Parameter Mapping tab.

[image]