# SSIS Script Component convert Object type variable to Int Variable

Tags: c#, ssis, script-component, dataflowtask

I need to load data from ODBC source to OLEDB destination. The OLEDB destination table does not contain Identity column but it does have a Primary key column where the values has to be inserted similar to Identity column(increment it by 1).

I have queried the destination table(OLEDB Source) and have retrieved the max(Id) and assigned to an SSIS variable of Object type and using Script Component from Data Flow to get the `max(Id)+1` value row by row.

While converting the Object type variable to Integer type, I get error as

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'System.IConvertible'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{805E3B62-B5E9-393D-8941-377D8BF4556B}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

The column from destination table can not be altered.

MaxUID = Object Variable

RowNumber = Output variable

Script Component Code

```cs
int i = 1;

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    Row.RowNumber = Convert.ToInt32(this.Variables.MaxUID) + 1;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use a variable of type `Int` ?

Comment: Its a DB2 Ole db source, not able to connect using Execute-T-SQL tasks
Currently I am using Third party tool Kingsway Soft to connect to the destination to retrieve the max(Id) value and using RecordSet component to store it in ObjectType Variable.  Recordset only allows Object type vaariable for storing the value dynamically.

Comment: You should be able to store the scalar integer value of this ODBC query instead of the result recordset.

Comment: Can you please suggest how can i achieve this.

Comment: [How to set a variable using a scalar-valued tSQL function in SSIS SQL Task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14965132/205233) shows how to do it. With the current version (SQL 2019) it's even possible to use the column name instead of the column index as shown in the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

This are the steps you need:

1. Prepare an OleDb Connection to the database you intend to query the `MAX(id)` from.
2. Declare a Variable `MaxUID` of type Int32 (or Int64 if necessary)
3. Add an "Execute SQL Task" to your package.
4. Configure your "Execute SQL Task" like this:

   *"General"* Tab
   ***ResultSet*** = "Single Row"
   ***SourceType*** = "Direct Input"
   ***SQL Statement*** = `SELECT max(Id)+1 FROM your_table_name AS [MaxUID]`

   *"Result Set"* Tab
   ***Result Name*** = `MaxUID`
   ***Variable Name*** = `User::MaxUID`

Now you have a Variable of type integer you can use in your Script Task.

---

Side note: If you only use this script task to increment the MaxUID value would an Expression Task be much easier?